# Select certain page on condition in vba

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am writing a script that extract tables from Word file as copies it to a worksheet in Excel. However, the Word files I received do not have the same format and the tables I need are not always on the same page. Hence I cannot use the regular table index.
Each table is on a different page and only on that page there somewhere is a text string (may or may not be in the table itself) like 'material/material list'. What I'd like to do is scan each page of the Word document for a certain textstring and only if that string is present, use the corresponding table on that page. Is this possible and how would I go about this?

A complication of the inconsistent formatting is that on some pages, the data is not even in a table so for those files I'd like an alert if the trigger word is found on a page but no table is there.

Edited:

I have tried to redefine the range considered. My hope is that this is the easiest method; see where the keyword occurs and then use the first table after that. However this does not seem to work.

```
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .Text = "Equipment"
    .Forward = True
    .Execute
    If .Found = True Then Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)
End With
```

Edit:
I tried to combine the code from macropod with a vba in Excel that copies the table to the worksheet.

```
Sub LookForWordDocs()
Dim FolderName As String
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Show
  On Error Resume Next
  FolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
  Err.Clear
  On Error GoTo 0
End With
    Dim sFoldPath As String: sFoldPath = FolderName     ' Change the path. Ensure that your have "\" at the end of your path
    Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject                    ' Requires "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference
    Dim oFile As File
    ' Loop to go through all files in specified folder
    For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sFoldPath).Files
        ' Check if file is a word document. (Also added a check to ensure that we don't pick up a temp Word file)
        If ((InStr(1, LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Path)), "doc", vbTextCompare) > 0) Or _
         (InStr(1, LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Path)), "docx", vbTextCompare) > 0)) And _
                (InStr(1, oFile.Name, "~$") = 0) And _
                ((InStr(1, oFile.Name, "k") = 1) Or (InStr(1, oFile.Name, "K") = 1)) Then
            ' Call the UDF to copy from word document
            ImpTable oFile
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Sub ImpTable(ByVal oFile As File)
Dim oWdApp As New Word.Application
Dim oWdDoc As Word.Document
Dim oWdTable As Word.Table
Dim oWS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lLastRow$, lLastColumn$
Dim s As String
s = "No correct table found"

With Excel.ThisWorkbook
Set oWS = Excel.Worksheets.Add
On Error Resume Next
oWS.Name = oFile.Name
On Error GoTo 0
Set sht = oWS.Range("A1")

Set oWdDoc = oWdApp.Documents.Open(oFile.Path)
oWdDoc.Activate
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFnd As String, Rng As Word.Range, i As Long, j As Long
j = 0
StrFnd = "equipment"
 With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = StrFnd
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    i = .Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
    Set Rng = Word.ActiveDocument.Goto(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i)
    Set Rng = Rng.Goto(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
    If Rng.Tables.Count > 0 Then
      With Rng.Tables(1)
      Set oWdTable = Rng.Tables(1)
        oWdTable.Range.Copy
        sht.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
        j = 1
       End With
    End If
    .Start = Rng.End
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
If j = 0 Then sht.Value = s
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
oWdDoc.Close savechanges:=False
oWdApp.Quit
End With

Set oWS = Nothing
Set sht = Nothing
Set oWdDoc = Nothing
Set oWdTable = Nothing
Set Rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

For the first file, the code works fine. However on the second run I get a run-time error "The remote Server Machine does not Exist or is unavailable" on line
"Word.ActiveDocument.Range". I added a couple of qualifications for elements but this still did not solve the problem. Am I missing another line?

BTW When I place "Word" before ActiveDocument.Range the code does not work any more.

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: @Luuklag love it! :). plaene, what have you tried so far.. I think that's what Luuklag is trying to get at.. brilliantly!

Comment: @Zac, yes that was what I was trying to get at. This question is far too broad to get any good quality answer. If plaene would like to have any usefull answers he better ask a more specific question.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear enough. What I tried to do is segment the Word file in pages as you would see them in Word and check per section if it matches a condition and subsequently import the table. However I understand from https://shaunakelly.com/word/word-development/selecting-or-referring-to-a-page-in-the-word-object-model.html that this would not be possible. I also looked into a simple script to check the Word file until a key word pops up, delete everything before that and then take the first table. As I see it this is only possible in strings and would not properly handle tables.

Comment: I want to double-check that I understand you correctly: Search the document (in a loop) for the phrase. Get the Range of each page on which the phrase is found. Check the Range for a table and "get" the table if present. If no table is present, notification. This is all possible using VBA, but before I put in any time writing code I want to be sure that's exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is not necessarily searching the whole document in a loop, but that was one of my thoughts. Somewhere in the document there is a keyword and I would like to extract the table immediately following that keyword. The rest of the document can then be disregarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've changed the text from 'material/material list' to 'Equipment', it's a bit hard to know quite what you want. Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFnd As String, Rng As Range, i As Long
StrFnd = InputBox("What is the Text to Find")
If Trim(StrFnd) = "" Then Exit Sub
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = StrFnd
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    i = .Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
    Set Rng = ActiveDocument.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i)
    Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
    If Rng.Tables.Count > 0 Then
      MsgBox Chr(34) & StrFnd & Chr(34) & " and table found on page " & i & "."
      With Rng.Tables(1)
        'process this table
      End With
    Else
      MsgBox Chr(34) & StrFnd & Chr(34) & " found on page " & i & " but no table."
    End If
    .Start = Rng.End
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Note:** the above code will test all pages on which the Find text is found.

Comment: That was mostly what I was looking for, thanks! However I need to run it from Excel and apply the code on multiple Word files. I adapted the code to import a Word file (and later this will be looped) but I get and "Argument not optional" error on the .start =rng.end . I added the following under demo: Dim oWdApp As New Word.Application
Dim oWdDoc As Word.Document
Dim oWdTable As Word.Table
Set oWdDoc = oWdApp.Documents.Open("path")
oWdDoc.Activate

Comment: Would it also be possible to extract the text in the footer of the page where the keyword is found?

Comment: Most likely you're getting the "Argument not optional" error because you haven't used 'Dim Rng As Word.Range' - which you might want to more clearly differentiate by using oWdRng throughout. Yes, it's possible to extract footer contents, but that's a different topic for which a new thread should be used.